# use of ## and # operator to concatenate the strings in a macro in C

Tags: c, macros, operator-keyword

I am having a code which requires to concatenate strings as shown below:

```
#define CMD(A,B)  CMD_##A_PROMPT##B

void main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    printf("%s\n", CMD(a, b));
}
```

the desired output is: `CMD10_PROMPT5`
Can this be achieved by any means?

Comment: Why do you need a macro? Is there something wrong with `printf("CMD%d_PROMPT%d\n",a,b);`? The values of `a` and `b` are run time properties so aren't available for macro expansion.

Comment: This macro would be used to call many macros which will be of the form:
CMD10_PROMPT5
CMD11_PROMPT6
CMD12_PROMT10 and so on, and each will have further definition...so the simple printf will not work

Comment: Why macros? As variable values change at run time, surely you need a function and not a macro?

Comment: I am having a big code and inorder to make the code compact, I was thinking of using this feature, but I guess I would not be able to use it.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this can be done, because the macro you're looking for is a *compile-time* "stringification", an the parameters receive their values at *run-time*.

If you're looking for run-time "stringification", use `sprintf` and the like.

Comment: Is there some way of combining the macros with variables and text?

Comment: Not in compile-time. Again, if you want a run-time combination of text with values stored in variables, use `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by replacing `int a = 10, b = 5;` with:

```
#define a 10
#define b 5
```

Otherwise it's not possible. C translation occurs in a series of phases defined in the standard, and preprocessing phase occurs before any object definitions are parsed. As far as the preprocessor is concerned, `int a = 10` does not establish any relationship between the token `a` and the token `10`.

If all you're after is the output, do it like this:

```
#define CMD_PATTERN "CMD_%d_PROMPT%d"

int main() {
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    printf(CMD_PATTERN "\n", a, b);
}
```

There's unfortunate requirement that the arguments are supplied in the same order that they appear in the pattern - this makes it difficult to change the order in future. For that reason, it might be better to define a formatting function rather than just a pattern.